# Remove CR+LF from a cell in CSV file

Tags: text-processing, csv

The data in column `b` has a `CR+LF` that shouldn't be there.  It looks likes this:

```
a,b,c
test1,test2
test2 bis,
test3
```

But it should look like this:

```
a,b,c
test1,test2 test2 bis,test3
```

How can I remove this with `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: See the comments you received under your previous identical question which you deleted for what you need to provide for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @EdMorton all i need is to remove [CRLF] from the column 'b'.

Comment: @EdMorton my question is very cleaer. Thanks for your time, i will wait for some one who know the answear.

Comment: Is there a specific requirement to use `awk` or `sed`? Is it always the same "specific column" you need to remove `CR LF` from? Does the CSV file have a fixed number of (nominal) columns per row? Can there be more that one column with `CR LF`?

Comment: @siraj you only think it's clear because you know in your head what you're asking about and only know the one thing you might mean by your question. To those of us who've seen a dozen different variations of this question with different requirements based on similar but different data formats and values, it's not clear at all from your question so far which of those many variants applies to your case, hence the feedback under your previous question (and now starting to reappear under this question) asking for those details so we could help you. Good luck.

Comment: @AdminBee yes the csv have a fixed number of columns, i want to remove CR LF only on column "b"

Comment: @EdMorton i found your comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994244/how-to-remove-newlines-inside-csv-cells-using-regex-terminal-tools im looking for something like this

Comment: @siraj make sure to [edit] your question to provide all requirements and examples, don't add them in comments where they can't be formatted and could be missed. I know YOU think your question is clear but, speaking as someone who's answered hundreds of similar questions, I promise you it is not and I and others have already told you what information is missing and how to provide it so I'm not sure what else to say except to repeat - see the comments you received under your previous identical question which you deleted for what you need to provide for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for posting your question. @aborruso has a good answer, if your data has the necessary quotes around the data with the line break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a wrong CSV. If you have a carriage return, you must have `"` around the cell value that contains the carriage return:

```
a,b,c
aaa,"test2
test2 bis",ccc
```

Starting from it, it's easy using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller).

Running

```
mlr --csv put -S '$b=gsub($b,"\n"," ")' input.csv>output.csv
```

you will have

```
a,b,c
test1,test2 test2 bis,test3
```